# Filling in the missing times of a broken time series set of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I downloaded per minute data from Google Analytics. However, it only provides a line item for each minute that there is a value greater than zero.

I would like to graph this data, but before I do I want to see it in a continuous time series, injecting explicit zeroes for the minutes where the source has no data.

I've converted the 'Hour of Day' (column `A`) and 'Minute' (column `B`) into 'Time' (column `G`) using

```
=TIME(RIGHT(A3,2),B3,0)
```

I tried using an index/match

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$954,MATCH(H3,$G$3:$G$954,0))
```

in column `I` referencing the continuous time series in column `H`, to return the data in column `C` but it returns `#N/A`.

Here’s a screenshot showing the desired result, entered manually, in column `I`:

[image: Screen shot updated]

Since `H6` is `12:03:00 AM`, `I6` should contain `2`, which is the value from `C3`, since `G3` is `12:03:00 AM`.

Similarly, `H11` = `G4` = `12:08:00 AM` → `I11` = `C4` = `1`.

Rows whose `H` value isn’t present in column `G` should have a `0` in column `I`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turns out to be due to floating point discrepancies when you use Excel's Linear series fill to auto-fill the times in column `H`, compared to the times generated with the `TIME()` function.

This can be confirmed by entering `=H6-G3` in any cell, or by selecting `H6`, then pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note that while the <kbd>F2</kbd> method can be used to correct the time values one at a time, it is  not convenient to do so for any significant number of cells.

The solution is to generate the `Continuous Time` values with a formula.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot using OP's Formula]

Enter the following formula in `H3` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill as far past the end of the table's `H` column as required:

```dart
=IF(ISTEXT(H2),TIME(RIGHT(A3,2),0,0),TIME(HOUR(H2),MINUTE(H2)+1,0))
```

Note that the time values can be left as is, or converted to literal values by copying and then pasting as values.

As you can see, your index/match formula in column `I` will now pick up the Users from column `C` when a matching time exists in column `G`.

---

EDIT:

Whilst the above formula is "robust" and allows rows to be inserted/deleted above the header without breaking it, as Scott has pointed out (especially if copy/pasting as values), there is a simpler less robust version:

```dart
=TIME(RIGHT($A$3,2),ROW()-3,0)
```

Further simplifying this leads to the following simplest possible formula:

```dart
=TIME(0,ROW()-3,0)
```

---

The only thing left to do is to modify the formula to generate zeroes when the time is missing:

```dart
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$954,MATCH(H3,$G$3:$G$954,0)),0)
```

[image: Worksheet Screenshot using Modified Formula]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!! I thought I was on the right track. You guys have been soo helpful :)

Comment: @Britt You're welcome. Don't forget to "accept" the answer (by clicking on the grey tick at the top-left of the answer) to mark the question as resolved. That is also the proper way to say "thanks" as it rewards the answerer (and you) with reputation. PS If you really appreciated my help, once you reach 15+ reputation don't forget to come back and upvote my answer as well ;-)

Comment: You can do `H3` much more simply as ``=TIME(RIGHT(A$3,2), ROW()-3, 0)``.

Comment: @Scott Yes. But then the formula breaks if rows are inserted/deleted above the header. I'm in two minds as to which is better though: the simpler but less robust version, or the more complex but more robust version. For my personal use I always prefer robustness over simplicity. For answers on Super User, if the formula is already fairly complex, I try to do the less robust version (if I remember). I suppose in this case, if the formulas are copy-pasted as values, then the simpler formula would be better.

Comment: @Scott Your formula further simplifies to `=TIME(0,ROW()-3,0)`.

Comment: @Britt FYI I've updated the answer with a simpler formula for the `H` column.

Comment: @robinCTS: Well, yeah, if you assume that the OP wants the chart to start at midnight even if the data don’t. If the data start at 5 AM, that would result in 300 blank lines.